# WCF Service didn't reply, timeout encounters on a system behind firewall with NAT

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, firewall, nat

**I am encountering a strange problem, here is my scenario**

1. One WCF Service (named *WCF1*) is deployed on Web Server with basicHttpBinding (streaming enabled)
2. I've a Windows Service Application which consumes *WCF1*, and hosts a WCF Service (named *WCF2*) with namedPipeBinding (duplex).
3. A Windows Application which consumes *WCF2*, and handles events raised from it (because this service is duplex).

Now if I'm calling a function from windows application on *WCF2* which further calls a function of WCF1 on an ordinary machine it works successfully.
But when I'm doing this on a machine which is behind Hardware Firewall (with NAT enabled), function of *WCF2* called successfully, and function called from WCF2 on WCF1 failed with timeout expired. If I'm calling function of WCF1 directly without using WCF2, It works successfully. 
I know, In NAT duplex comm. is troublesome and is not supported in most cases. but There is no role of duplex in Communication between *WCF1* and *WCF2*,
If there is any role, Then how Can i prevent it...,
note: I cannot disable NAT